# Dynamically created custom validator does not add error message to validation summary

Tags: asp.net, customvalidator

could you please tell me, why custom validator (created dynamically), information here is not added to validation summary? Is it because of updatepanel? How to make it work?
I am absolutely exhausted, but cannot find appropriate solution...

### MultiFreeSet control code-behind:

```
protected void btnPatternAdder_Click(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    var includeEventArgs = new IncludeEventArgs();
    baseTSMAlertConfigEditControlWithInclude.btnPatternAdder_Click(sender, includeEventArgs);
    if (includeEventArgs.Cancel)
    {
        /*
        var ClientValidationFunctionName = string.Format("{0}_ClientValidation", ID);
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
                                                GetType(),
                                                string.Format("{0}_validationScript", ID),
                                                string.Format("function {0}(sender, eventArgs) {{ eventArgs.errormessage = '{1}', eventArgs.IsValid = false; return; }}",
                                                ClientValidationFunctionName,
                                                includeEventArgs.Message));
        */
        var customValidator = new CustomValidator
        {
            //ClientValidationFunction = ClientValidationFunctionName,
            ValidationGroup = ValidationGroup,
            IsValid = false,
            ErrorMessage = includeEventArgs.Message,
            Display = ValidationDisplayType
        };
        Page.Validators.Add(customValidator);
    }
}
```

### MultiFreeSet control markup:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upFreeSet" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
...
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="phIncludePattern" Visible="false">
    <tr>
        <td class="SubHead">[IncludeCaption]</td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtIncludePattern" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="MediumTextBox" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button CommandName="ListAdder" ID="btnPatternAdder" runat="server" CssClass="buttonClass displayBlock" Text="Add" OnClick="btnPatternAdder_Click" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="SubHead ta">[IncludedCaption]</td>
        <td>
            <asp:ListBox ID="lboxIncludePattern" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Rows="7" CssClass="LargeDropDownList" />
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsIncludePattern" runat="server" />
</td>
<td class="ta">
<asp:Button CommandName="ListDeleter" ID="btnPatternDeleter" runat="server" CssClass="buttonClass displayBlock" Text="Delete selected" OnClick="btnPatternDeleter_Click" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
...
</ContentTemplate>
```

### Main control markup:

```
<asp:FormView>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        ...
        <ac:multiFreeSet ID="multiNodePatternInclusions" ValidationGroup="vgFrmConfigEdit" IgnoreCase="True" runat="server" Caption="Include node name patterns" IncludeCaption="Add node name pattern" IncludedCaption="Included node name patterns" />
        <XXX:SaveButton ID="btnImgSave" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vgFrmConfigEdit" />
        <XXX:CancelBackButton ID="btnImgCancel" runat="server" />
        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="valSummary" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vgFrmConfigEdit" CssClass="NormalRed" ShowSummary="True" />
        ...
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

Comment: After the postback, the validator is no more in the control tree. That's why this does not validate

Comment: I cannot move Validation Summary control into updatepanel, too, because it's used for other validate controls, on the same level as multifreeset. If it's not possible to sort things out with the same validation summary - at least tell me please, how to give some alert to the user in Add Button click event. For now, I was not able even to make simple alert with error message text to show...

Comment: Steve B - the point is that validation itself happens, wrong data does not go throw :) It's just that there is no any message to the user shown...

Comment: I've created CustomValidator in markup and just assign properties in OnClick, including ClientValidationFunction. So now this validator IS in control tree. But message is not shown anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Well.. I had to create a separate validation summary with separate validation group inside update panel..